How to add a cover image to an asciidoc document
Here is my asciidoc document header:
= My App: Software Design Document
Giuseppe Greco <giuseppe.greco@agamura.com>
v.0.1, 2024-09-18: First draft
:doctype: book
:sectnums:
:toc:
:toclevels: 4
:description: Software Design Document
:imagesdir: ./images
:appname: myApp
:front-cover-image: image::cover-page.svg[alt="Cover Page", width=600, height=400, align="center"]

I want to add a cover page before any other page... but unfortunately the front-cover-image directive above doesn't work. cover-page.svg is located in imagesdir. Am I missing something?

This is just a guess, but you are using block image macro (image::). Try using an inline image macro (image:), as that's what appears in the examples I've seen.

No, unfortunately using an inline image macro doesn't work either.

For Asciidoctor PDF, you have two choices:

Configure the title page in your AsciiDoc content: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/title-page/

Configure your theme:

to use a cover: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/title-page/
to use a title page: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/title-pages/



As Richard Smith commented, you likely need to use an inline image instead of a block image, so image: instead of image::.
